# OR statement in SQL command does not function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know to fix the error? I would like to create the `OR` statement but it does not function in my code. The code is shown below. I have removed the `OR` to see the code function or not, it can function if I remove the or statement. So I desperately want to know what the real problem with my code is.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data; 

public partial class updateform : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM [EMP] WHERE Serial_Num='" + TextBox2.Text + "' or Equipment_ID ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        TextBox3.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
        TextBox4.Text = dt.Rows[0][6].ToString();
        DropDownList1.Text = dt.Rows[0][7].ToString();
        TextBox5.Text = dt.Rows[0][18].ToString();
        TextBox6.Text = dt.Rows[0][11].ToString();
        TextBox11.Text = dt.Rows[0][8].ToString();
        TextBox7.Text = dt.Rows[0][20].ToString();
        TextBox12.Text = dt.Rows[0][17].ToString();
        DropDownList2.Text = dt.Rows[0][23].ToString();
        TextBox9.Text = dt.Rows[0][14].ToString();
        TextBox10.Text = dt.Rows[0][13].ToString();
        TextBox13.Text = dt.Rows[0][12].ToString();
        TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
        TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source =.\\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog = test; Integrated Security = True");
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE EMP SET Model='" + TextBox3.Text + "' ,Description= '" + TextBox4.Text + "' ,Location='" + DropDownList1.Text + "',Manufacturer_or_Vendor= '" + TextBox5.Text + "',NCR_or_OOT_History='" + TextBox6.Text + "',Due_date= '" + TextBox11.Text + "' ,Year_of_Manufacturing='" + TextBox12.Text + "',Asset_No= '" + TextBox7.Text + "' ,Status='" + DropDownList2.Text + "',Responsible_Person= '" + TextBox9.Text + "',Available_in_Sapphire= '" + TextBox10.Text + "',Last_OOT_issuance_Date= '" + TextBox13.Text + "' WHERE (Serial_Num = '" + TextBox2.Text + "' or Equipment_ID = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' )", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

    protected void Page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = false;
            Calendar2.Visible = false;
            Calendar3.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Calendar1.Visible)
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
   {
        if (Calendar2.Visible)
        {
            Calendar2.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Calendar2.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    protected void ImageButton3_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Calendar3.Visible)
        {
            Calendar3.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Calendar3.Visible = true;
        }
    }

protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox11.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar1.Visible = false;
}

protected void Calendar2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox12.Text = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar2.Visible = false;
}

protected void Calendar3_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox13.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar3.Visible = false;
}

protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.IsOtherMonth)
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;

    }
}

protected void Calendar2_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.IsOtherMonth)
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
    }
}

protected void Calendar3_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.IsOtherMonth)
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
    }
}

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
}
```

Comment: You should use prepared statements, which might avoid some of the trouble you are having now.

Comment: How does it "not function"? Please add the error-message or your expected and actual output.

Comment: @piet.t 
the data  do not appear in the text box. the purpose of my code is when user click on search button. the data will be display in the text box. However, it only display if i remove the or statement.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your description whether it fails at compile time or execution time, or what the error is. But a wild guess of what could be the problem, try the followings:

1. Instead of Select * try specifying the actual columns (like select col1, col2, ..
2. Instead of:

   sda.Fill(dt);

Declare a dataset and fill the dataset and see if it works.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet (); 
sda.Fill (ds);
```

If this works, check and see how many tables are created in your dataset and what records are in each table.

Comment: it do not appear in the text box. the purpose of my code is when user click on search button. the data will be display in the text box. However, it only display if i remove the or statement.